# How to delete text in data where there should be numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, stata

I have the following numeric variable in Stata:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input long r_3srhlt
3
3
2
2
4
1
1
3
3
4
end
label values r_3srhlt r_3srhlt
label def r_3srhlt 1 ".", modify
label def r_3srhlt 2 "2.very ...", modify
label def r_3srhlt 3 "3.good", modify
label def r_3srhlt 4 "5.poor", modify
```

I would like to keep just the number and not the text.

For example I want `3, 3, 2, 2, 5, . , . , 3, 3, 5` without the "good", "very good", "poor" etc. My data was originally a Stata file that I `read` via `Haven`in R. After doing some manipulations on the file I imported them back to Stata.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a numeric variable, which you first need to convert to a string:

```
decode r_3srhlt, generate(r_3srhlt_string)
```

Then you can get all numbers in one go using the `real()` function and a simple regular expression:

```
generate wanted = real(ustrregexs(0)) if ustrregexm(r_3srhlt_string, "[0-9]*")

list, separator(0) abbreviate(15)

     +---------------------------------------+
     |   r_3srhlt   r_3srhlt_string   wanted |
     |---------------------------------------|
  1. |     3.good            3.good        3 |
  2. |     3.good            3.good        3 |
  3. | 2.very ...        2.very ...        2 |
  4. | 2.very ...        2.very ...        2 |
  5. |     5.poor            5.poor        5 |
  6. |          .                 .        . |
  7. |          .                 .        . |
  8. |     3.good            3.good        3 |
  9. |     3.good            3.good        3 |
 10. |     5.poor            5.poor        5 |
     +---------------------------------------+
```